# SFTP through ssh node

Tags: ssh, sftp, tunnel

I'm trying to set up an sftp on a networked server. I can access the machine through the outside world by first ssh'ing into a network login server through the following process:

```
ssh [network-username]@login.server.co.uk
```

then, once logged in

```
ssh [server-username]@[hostname]
```

Is there anyway to sftp into the networked server? I cant find a way to add the initial step into the login process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified what SFTP client you are using.

In general, some SFTP clients DO allow SSH tunneling.

WinSCP for instance.
See [Connect to FTP/SFTP server which can be accessed via another server only](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel).

OpenSSH suite allows that too.
For example see [Forward SSH traffic through a middle machine](https://superuser.com/q/107679/213663).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*